# Breeze data.results not load nested JSON

Tags: breeze

I have the next hierarchical class:

```
public class HClass
{
    public HClass()
    {
        Children = new List<HClass>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }        
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<HClass> Children { get; set; }
}
```

I have a method in Controller that return Parents and Children:

```
[HttpGet]
public IQueryable<HClass> Items()
```

I have a function in my viewmodel:

```
function getItems() {
        return entityQuery.from('Items')
            .using(manager).execute()
            .then(success)
            .fail(queryFailed);

        function success(data) {
            vm.items = data.results; //Problem here.
        }
    }
```

In debug mode I review that "`data.XHR.responseText`" have a nested JSON complete with all items with their respective array of children, but "`data.results`" only have Parents without Children.

Please, help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design, data.results has the "immediate" results that you queried, i.e the top level 'items'. However, if you drill into the "Children" property of any of the results items, you should see the children.

If this is not the case, then check that you are using the [BreezeController] attribute on your ApiController class.  This attribute configures the JSON.NET serializer to add a '$type' property to each json 'entity'.  If you don't see this property, it's a fair bet that you are missing the attribute. Without the $type infomation breeze will not recognize the children as entities and will ignore them.

( Side note, you can also use a JsonResultsAdapter or the [JsonFormatter] attribute to do something similar, but the [BreezeController] approach is the simpler)

Comment: I am using [BreezeController] attribute `[BreezeController] public class MyController : ApiController {...}`, but when I drill into Children property this is empty.

Comment: You mentioned that the data.XHR.responseText has "a nested JSON complete with all items with their respective array of children". If so then, does the $type property appear on the children.

Comment: Yes, I cut a part of jSON: `[{"$id":"1","$type":"Project.Entities.HClass, Project.Entities","Id":1,"Name":"Item 1","Children":[{"$id":"2","$type":"Project.Entities.HClass, Project.Entities","Id":26,"ParentId":1,"Name":"Item 26","Children":[{...`

Comment: How was the metadata defined? Is this a unidirectional navigation or a bidirectional navigation.  If unidirectional, i.e. Parents -> Children but not Child -> Parent, try making the association bidirectional. There is a known bug with unidirectional navigations where only parent -> children is defined.

Comment: Is a unidirectional navigation, thanks for information I will try the "association bidirectional".

Comment: The "association bidirectional" fixed the issue. Thanks.